# What would you call a collection of different types of software and hardware components?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word or term that comprises all of these into a single entity.

Comment: How do you propose to use such a word?

Comment: Either "system" or "conglomeration", depending on how much you believe it was actually designed vs just colliding accidentally.

Comment: You mean *compose* not *comprise*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the word "system" encapsulates both together working in tandem, i.e. a computer system, to be more precise.